# Please help identify this sans-serif font

Tags: fonts, font-identification, sans-serif

What sans-serif font is this? Notice that the "S" goes thin at the top end.

[image: Select Your Clientlist written in the font]

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GD. There are a lot of resources we will ask you to try first (http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info), and if/when you have tried them, please update your question and let us know. Always good to show a little effort, and it saves time.

Comment: Hello again! The idea just came into my mind a few minutes ago. Can you please link us to the website where this font is used? Thanks!

Comment: Hi , It was not a site where this font was used . One of the designer used it in the designs . When I tired to implement it i could not get a hold of the font type . :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like the [**Aller Typo**](http://www.identifont.com/show?285Q) font:

[image]

Comment: I think I’d have to agree; here’s the link to Dalton Maag’s site: http://www.daltonmaag.com/buyonline/fonts/aller

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty low-quality sample but, in general terms, you've got a font somewhere between [**Meta Condensed**](https://typekit.com/fonts/ff-meta-web-pro-condensed) and [**Myriad Condensed**](https://typekit.com/fonts/myriad-pro-condensed).

Comment: @Nuk Can I ask you, why Aller Typo is not a right answer?

Comment: Aller Type is the correct answer . @llan

Answer (score 0):

It is Open Sans Condensed font from google fonts.

[image]

Comment: Similar, but the l in Open Sans doesn't have the same tail as in the sample

Comment: Oh right. Yeah.

Comment: thank you for the help .  i agree with you the tail is not matching . I searched a lot but didnt get that font . one of the designers used this font in one of the web page design but he left the job . So we got stuck .

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm sure it's one of google's fonts. Maybe try the suggestion from the answer below? I haven't checked those fonts yet but if I ever come across this font you're trying to find, I'll let you know!